# In flux vs. radius equation, isn't there a mistake in the dimensions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

The video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m13kKLHhN6Y

The equations given are:

$\frac{Energy}{Seconds} = \frac{L . A}{4 \pi r^2}$ where $L$ is the luminosity, $A$ area and $r$ is the radius.

$Flux = \frac{L}{4 \pi r^2}$ where Flux is the energy per unit area

Now, using the first equation, we can clearly see that the unit of $L$ is $energy/time$. However, if that is the case, then in the second equation, shouldn't we multiply by *time* in order to make the equation dimensionally  correct?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right. You need to multiply by time on the right hand side to get the correct dimensions.

Comment: So, those equations given by Prof. Brian Schmidt were incorrect?

Comment: @MathEnthusiast Thats what it looks like.